# ASP.Net C# Controller Return DataTable in Ajax view Server Side Processing

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, datatable

I tried to controller return datatable from ajax but got error:

```
DataTables warning: table id=tbl_model - Invalid JSON response.
```

[Full error text window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mF7FB.png).
For more information about this error, please see details on `datatables.net` [datatables - 1. Warning: Invalid JSON response](http://datatables.net/tn/1)

Below is my source code
**View**

```
   <thead>
     <tr>
       <th class="text-center"></th>
       <th class="text-center"><b>User</b></th>
       <th class="text-center"><b>Activity</b></th>
       <th class="text-center"><b>Date</b></th>
     </tr>
    </thead>
  </table>
```

```
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.4/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#tbl_model").DataTable({
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "filter": true,
            "ajax": {
                "url": "@Url.Action("UserAuditTrail", "AuditTrail")",
                "type": "POST",
                "datatype": "json"
            },
            "columnDefs": [{
                targets: 0,
                render: function (data, type, row, meta) {
                    return meta.row + meta.settings._iDisplayStart + 1;
                }
            }],
            "columns": [
                { "data": "fld_ID", "name": "Id", "autoWidth": true },
                { "data": "fld_CreatedBy", "name": "User", "autoWidth": true },
                { "data": "fld_UserActivity", "name": "Activity", "autoWidth": true },
                { "data": "fld_CreatedDT", "name": "Date", "autoWidth": true },
            ]
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Controller**

```
public DataTable UserAuditTrail()
 {
    int currentYear = DateTime.Now.Year;
    var getdata = db.tblUserAuditTrails.Where(x => x.fld_CreatedDT.Value.Year == currentYear).OrderBy(o => o.fld_CreatedDT).ToList();
    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(getdata);
    DataTable dt = (DataTable)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json, (typeof(DataTable)));
    return dt;
 }
```

**Controller Return**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bC6X4.png)

Return datatable with server side processing.

Comment: Are you getting data in your console as expected? Could include few demo data within your question?

Comment: Why are you serializing the data to JSON and then deserializing into a DataTable class? You should just be returning the JSON.

Comment: Your error message says: "_For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/1 ._" So - did you do that? Did you read the "Meaning", "Diagnosis", and "Resolution" guidance provided there?

Comment: Basically, you need to provide the DataTable in a standard web page (HTML and JavaScript). Then, as a completely separate piece of coding you need to handle the Ajax request from that DataTable - and provide a response as JSON (as [noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76180548/asp-net-c-sharp-controller-return-datatable-in-ajax-view-server-side-processing#comment134345644_76180548) by @JohnM). You can't send the DataTable to the DataTable.

Comment: Hello have you tried the solution provided? Is there anything else that I can help you on this?

Answer (score 0):

> ASP.Net C# Controller Return DataTable in Ajax view Server Side
> Processing

Based on your shared code you can directly return `getdata` and  Serialization and Deserialization is not necessary in order to populate data table.

I have tested your scenario as following and working as expcted:

Controller:

```
        [HttpPost]
        public IEnumerable<tblUserAuditTrails> UserAuditTrail()
        {

            List<tblUserAuditTrails> ListOfUserAudit = new List<tblUserAuditTrails>()
            {
                new tblUserAuditTrails(){ fld_ID = 1, fld_CreatedBy = "A", fld_UserActivity = "Activity-1", fld_CreatedDT = DateTime.Now},
                new tblUserAuditTrails(){ fld_ID = 2, fld_CreatedBy = "B", fld_UserActivity = "Activity-2", fld_CreatedDT = DateTime.Now},
                new tblUserAuditTrails(){ fld_ID = 3, fld_CreatedBy = "C", fld_UserActivity = "Activity-3", fld_CreatedDT = DateTime.Now},
                new tblUserAuditTrails(){ fld_ID = 4, fld_CreatedBy = "D", fld_UserActivity = "Activity-3", fld_CreatedDT = DateTime.Now},


            };
            return ListOfUserAudit;

        }
```

View:

```
<table id="tbl_model" class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive nowrap" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="text-center"></th>
            <th class="text-center"><b>User</b></th>
            <th class="text-center"><b>Activity</b></th>
            <th class="text-center"><b>Date</b></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>

@section scripts {
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.4/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#tbl_model').DataTable({
                processing: true,
                serverSide: true,
                filter: true,
                "ajax": {
                    "url": "@Url.Action("UserAuditTrail","ControllerName")",
                    "type": "POST",
                    "datatype": "json",
                    "dataSrc": function (msg) {
                        console.log(msg);
                        return msg;
                    }
                },
                "columnDefs": [{
                    targets: 0,
                    render: function (data, type, row, meta) {
                        return meta.row + meta.settings._iDisplayStart + 1;
                    }
                }],
                "columns": [
                    { "data": "fld_ID", "name": "Id", "autoWidth": true },
                    { "data": "fld_CreatedBy", "name": "User", "autoWidth": true },
                    { "data": "fld_UserActivity", "name": "Activity", "autoWidth": true },
                    { "data": "fld_CreatedDT", "name": "Date", "autoWidth": true },
                ]
            });

        });
    </script>
}
```

Output:

[image]